# Spring Boot Dashboard not available in Eclipse Version: 2020-06

Tags: spring-tools-4

I just installed a fresh download of Eclipse version: 2020-06 (4.16.0) and then installed the Spring Tool Suite 4 for Eclipse (4.6.2 update e4.16) on Windows 10.

It seems there is **no Spring Boot Dashboard** which **was available in Eclipse 4.15**.

**How do I make the Spring Boot Dashboard available in Eclipse 4.16?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the latest release that got published a few moments ago. Please install the just released Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.7.0, that should bring the boot dashboard back.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin!
It works now after upgraded to the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

I Installed eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0) in ubuntu Linux 20.04 from Ubuntu Software.

In Eclipse marketplace I searched for STS and install: Spring Tools 3 (Standalone Edition):

[Menu: Help/Eclipse MarketPlace...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWJ7M.png)

after in: Menu: Window/Show View/Other in the Spring folder I picked Boot Dashboard:

[Menu: Window/Eclipse Marketplace/STS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR98k.png)